# Fences (parenthesis, braces) in HTML and MathML

Tags: html, mathml

Using MathML, inside <mrow>, I have an expression that is quite big (once rendered, the symbols occupy more space in vertical than the normal text). When I add a <mo>(<\mo> inside the same <mrow>, the parenthesis is enlarged to match the size of the expression.

For example:

```
 <math>
   <mrow>
     <mo>(</mo>

     <mfrac><mrow> <mn>1</mn> </mrow> <mrow> <msqrt><mrow>
     <mfrac><mrow> <mi>a</mi> </mrow> <mrow> <mi>b</mi> </mrow>
     </mfrac> </mrow> </msqrt> </mrow> </mfrac>

     <mo>)</mo>
   </mrow>
 </math>
```

is rendered as:

[image: expression in parenthesis]

Other symbols, such as "+", are not enlarged, not even if they are inside a <mo>. I would like to have brackets
like "< expr >", but the following code:

```
 <math>
   <mrow>
     <mo><</mo>

     <mfrac><mrow> <mn>1</mn> </mrow> <mrow> <msqrt><mrow>
     <mfrac><mrow> <mi>a</mi> </mrow> <mrow> <mi>b</mi> </mrow>
     </mfrac> </mrow> </msqrt> </mrow> </mfrac>

     <mo>></mo>
   </mrow>
 </math>
```

does not enlarge the "<" and ">":

[image: expression in < >]

It seems that the behavior of the various symbols is automatically selected, so that
"(" is considered as a fence and "<" is not. Is it possible to override this choice,
so that the "<" and ">" are resized? I tried various options of <mo> but none worked.